# Check first install or update in write manner in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an existing app in ios now I want to integrate some code to check whether the app is first install or updated or same version. but the problem is that if an old user update the app the first launch is working while the app is updated.Can anybody tell me how to handle it ?

Answer (score 3):

You could save a version number to NSUserDefaults, and update it accordingly.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// ...

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *currentAppVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *previousVersion = [defaults objectForKey:@"appVersion"];
if (!previousVersion) {
    // first launch

    // ...

    [defaults setObject:currentAppVersion forKey:@"appVersion"];
    [defaults synchronize];
} else if ([previousVersion isEqualToString:currentAppVersion]) {
    // same version
} else {
    // other version

    // ...

    [defaults setObject:currentAppVersion forKey:@"appVersion"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}



return YES;
}
```

Comment: I used same code but if an old existing user updates app the first launch function call but I want if an old user update app update version function should be execute